# How can I write a function in R which accepts column names like dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am writing a package with several functions that accept a dataframe object as well as the the dataframe's column names as arguments.

Here is a simplified example:

```
func = function(df,vars){
    head(df[,vars])
}

#column args as strings
func(mtcars,c("mpg","cyl"))
```

Instead of supplying the column names as strings, I would like the function to accept (and suggest/auto-complete) the column names like in dplyr functions.

```
#dplyr-style args
func(mtcars, mpg, cyl)

#which doesnt work because mpg and cyl don't exist as objects
```

I considered using the `...` as function arguments but this would still involve using strings.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot get autocomplete as that is done by the IDE. You nee to use `deparse` and `substitute` for the names to be used in the way you wish.

Comment: Note that dplyr does not have auto-complete/suggest. This is within magrittr package. ie once you use the `%>%` then you have the variables available. Right now, even though your function does not work, having `mtcars %>%func()` then press `tab` key will give you list of all the variables available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution, using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

func = function(df,...){
  df %>% 
    select(...) %>% 
    head
}


func(mtcars, mpg, cyl)
#>                    mpg cyl
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8
#> Valiant           18.1   6

func(mtcars, mpg)

#>                    mpg
#> Mazda RX4         21.0
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0
#> Datsun 710        22.8
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7
#> Valiant           18.1
```

---

Or in `base R`:

```r
func = function(df,...){
  head(df[, sapply(substitute(...()), deparse)])
}

func(mtcars, mpg, cyl)
#>                    mpg cyl
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8
#> Valiant           18.1   6

func(mtcars, mpg)

#> [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
subset(df, select = item)
```

You should check out [Advanced R by Hadley Wickham](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html) which is extremely interesting, if somewhat, well, advanced. In particular:

> 20.4 Data masks
>
> In this section, you’ll learn about the data mask, a data frame where
> the evaluated code will look first for variable definitions. The data
> mask is the key idea that powers base functions like with(), subset()
> and transform(), and is used throughout the tidyverse in packages like
> dplyr and ggplot2.